# django taking post request as get. django forms not working properly

Tags: python, django, forms

django is taking my post and get request, but the action of the form is returning the wrong url over and over.

(my html template):-

```
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font relative">
    <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">

        <div class="flex flex-col text-center w-full mb-12">
            <h1 class="sm:text-3xl text-2xl font-medium title-font mb-4 text-gray-900">Change Password</h1>
            <p class="lg:w-2/3 mx-auto leading-relaxed text-base">Change Your Accounts Password.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lg:w-1/2 md:w-2/3 mx-auto">
            <form action="/profile/change-password/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <div class="p-2 w-full">
                    <button
                        class="flex mx-auto text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Change</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

(views.py):-

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Password Changed Succesfully!")
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect("/profile/")

        else:
            messages.info(request, "Please Try Again.")
            return redirect("/change-password/")

    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request, "change_password.html", {'form': form})
```

(urls.py):-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", profile),
    path("edit-profile/", edit_profile),
    path("change-password/", change_password),
]
```

Please help

Comment: URL should be written in the form:

<form method="post" action="{% url 'app_name:url_name' %}">

also minor issue but i'd prefer to explicit "name=page_name" in url path 
standards are really relevant working with django imho